# MATLAB: page width line vs. publishing width

Tags: matlab, publish, code-formatting

When I write code in Matlab I make sure it is within the page width line of demarcation. I thought the purpose of this line was because it signified the width of a page, but when I use the publish option on my code, it wraps about 6 characters to the left of the demarcation line, onto the next line, which makes the publishing ugly.

Is there any way to fix this by either changing the line position or the publishing width (preferably the latter)?

Here's what my editor window looks like:

[image]

And here's the resulting PDF page from publishing this code:
[image]

(notice the wrap-around in line #2)

Comment: I don't get the same feature. Can you show some examples?

Comment: sure, making an edit now

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I hit the same ugliness and this is the best I could get:

[image]

The first comment was put as line by line in the editor, while the second commented chunk was put as a long single line, and I think the publisher decides where to cut which is a neater result, not perfect though.

Comment: That works fine with comments, but with code I don't want it to arbitrary go to the next line in the middle of a line of code :/